# Omitir un resultado en for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un bucle for iterando sobre un archivo txt para sustraer una cadena espesifica (Numero de cuit) el inconveniente es que en txt siempre hay 2 cuit, uno fijo y uno varia segun el archivo. Por ende quiero poner en el for una condicion que sea omitir cierto cuit (el fijo) para que itere sobre el resto del texto y me traiga el otro.
Dejo a continuacion el script y el txt.

```
def cuit():
elcuit = []
for x in re.findall(r'\d{2}-\d{8}-\d{1}', cadena) or re.findall(r'\d{11}', cadena):
    if len(x) >= 11:
        # x = re.sub('-','',x)
        # elcuit.append(int(x))
        elcuit.append(x)
        break
    else:
        if len(x) == 11:
            elcuit.append(int(x))
            break
print(f"Su Nro de cuit es: {elcuit}")
```

**Return**

```
Su Nro de cuit es: ['30-60001770-4']
```

Ahora bien ese es el que quiero evitar traer.

Txt:

```
 8 LA COOPERATIVA. 14/02/2023
J.M.                          5000 ROSARI O
 RESPONSABLE
COND. VENTA: 30 dias fecha de factura   30C.U.I.T.: 30-60001770-4- 19:06:59ORIGINAL
 Factura Nº  0000-00000000
Fecha y Hora:A
CANTIDAD DESCRIPCION PRECIO UNITARIO ALICUOTA IVA PRECIO NETOCódigo 01
C.U.I.T.: 30-51758324-1 <----ESTE CUIT QUIERO
Ingresos Brutos: 021-96246-0
Inicio de Actividades: 05/05/69
CAMBIO DE MANGUERA DE ALTA PRESION     1.00     63,88 4.30     63,884.30 (21.00)
SINIESTRO N° 12345678910 

63,884.30
TOTAL        $     77,300.00SUBTOTAL ALICUOTA IVA IVA$ PERCEPCIONES IVA PERCEPCIONE S OTROS CONCEPTOS NO GRAVADOS
21.00 13415.70
C.A.E.  Nº  0000000000000000
Fecha de Vencimiento: 24/02/2023Recibi(mos):   Cuenta Corriente                  $       77300.00
```

Hice el siguiente cambio en el codigo:

```
for x in re.findall(r'[!30-50001770-4]\d{2}-\d{8}-\d{1}', cadena) or re.findall(r'\d{11}', cadena):
```

Y el return es:

```
12345678910
```

Alguien tiene alguna posible solucion ?
Gracias!

Comment: El CUIT tiene el mismo formato para todo. No entiendo el ```\d{11}``` ¿son CUIT con esstructura numérica, es decir sin los guiones? Por en tu ejemplo has obtenido el número de siniestro

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich el \d{11} esta en un or aparte porque en otro txt el cuit aparece sin los - solo los 11 numeros de corrido, entonces para esa clase me sirve asi.
Mi intencion es general un script un tanto uniforme, que evalue si el cuit tiene - o no y me lo traiga de todos modos.

Comment: Entonces, en tu ejemplo, existen 3 CUIT: 30-60001770-4, 30-51758324-1, 12345678910. Eso es lo que no entiendo, porque en tu pregunta das como resultado el ultimo numero debiendo ser el 2. Ahora si el ultimo numero tambien debe ser extraido adicional a los otros, entonces, tu resultado deberia ser  30-51758324-1, 12345678910.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Nono el que seria nro de siniestro 12345678910 no deberia traerlo, ese es mi inconveniente. quiero ver como hacer para traer de vuelta solo el que necesito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tu script solo tienes que hacerle una pequeña modificación en la expresión regular:

```
 \b\d{2}[-]?\d{8}[-]?\d{1}\b
```

Como observarás los guiones son opcionales para aprovechar la extracción del numero de siniestro, por lo tanto, no necesitas un  *for*:

```
  x=re.findall(r'\b\d{2}[-]?\d{8}[-]?\d{1}\b', cadena)
  print(f"Su CUIT es: {x[1]}")
  print(f"Su N° de Siniestro es {x[2]}")
```

El *findall* te retorna un arreglo y este arreglo tendrá, considerando que el texto siempre viene en el mismo formato, el primer CUIT, el segundo CUIT y el numero de siniestro. Las etiquetas *\b* son importantes porque indican que deben se palabras completas. Si quieres evitar el número de siniestro le quitas *?* a la expresión y x[1] te traerá el segundo CUIT.

De acuerdo a tu comentario, quieres solamente el segundo CUIT, entonces, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
 x=re.findall(r".*((?:\b\d{2}[-]\d{8}[-]\d\b))", cadena, re.DOTALL)
 print(f"Su CUIT es: {x}")
```

Esta ultima expresión utiliza el .* inicial para que barra la cadena hasta el ultimo que cumpla con la expresión regular y el ultimo que la cumple es el segundo CUIT.

Ahora, si lo quieres más preciso:

```
 x=re.findall(r".*((?<=C[.]U[.]I[.]T[.]:\s)(?:\b\d{2}[-]\d{8}[-]\d\b))", cadena, re.DOTALL)
 print(f"Su CUIT es: {x}")
```

Comment: Bien si, eso me funciono perfecto, no supe de antemano la expresion \b. El tema es el siguiente si yo pongo:
`print(f"Su CUIT es: {x[0]}")`
Me trae de vuelta el primer cuit, si bien entiendo que funciona, mi intencion es usarlo para distintos formatos de txt y correR otra logica para encontrarlo.
Es por eso que use el for con un OR para que funcione con una formula u otra.
Dentro de la expresion regular no se puede decir que no me traiga este cuit 30-60001770-4? Como negarle ese numero para que lo pase por alto y siga?

Comment: Bueno logre hacer lo que pensaba ordenando de forma distinta, o bien podria solo quitar el cuit empresa
`for x in re.findall(r'\b\d{2}[-]\d{8}[-]\d{1}\b', cadena) or re.findall(r'\d{11}', cadena):`
        `if len(x) >= 11:`
            `x = re.sub('-','',x)`
            `if x == "30600017704":`
                `cuitempresa.append(int(x))`
            `else:`
                `elcuit.append(int(x))`
        `else:`
            `if len(x) == 11:`
               `elcuit.append(int(x))`
    `print(f"Su Nro de cuit es: {elcuit}")`
    `print(f"Su Nro de cuit empresa es: {cuitempresa}")`

Comment: Bueno, tu solución es prácticamente lo que hago con x[0] y x[1] con ? en guiones pero con diferente nombre, sin embargo, tú sabes lo que se acomoda mas a lo que quieres y me alegro hayas superado tu problema.